# DataGrid want to display NO RECORDS

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid

In my application i am using DataGrid,i am binding dataset to that DataGrid.So if the dataset records is zero i want to display "NO ReCORDS FOUND" in my DataGrid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your current code?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `EmptyDataText`  property in a `DataGrid`, so in your code-behind do something like

```
if (dgTest.Items.Count == 0)
{
    lblEmpty.Visible = true;
    lblEmpty.Text = "Empty";
}
```

Where `dgTest` is the ID of the `DataGrid` and `lblEmpty` is a placeholder label.

Comment: Better to have.                                                   if (dgTest.Items.Count<1)
{
    lblEmpty.Visible = true;
    lblEmpty.Text = "Empty";
}
else 
{
    lblEmpty.Visible = false;    
}

Answer (score 0):

You have GridView tag as well so for GridView, you can set it's `EmptyDataText` property to `"No records found"` . It's a little complicated with `DataGrid`.